# Positivity of the anti-commutator of two positive operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If I take the anti-commutator of two positive operators $A,B$ on a Hilbert space,
$AB+BA$ is again guaranteed to be Hermitian, but is it also necessarily positive?

Comment: Actually, I just found a counter-example using 2-dimensional complex matrices, so please ignore this question. So, the answer is NO, in general the anti-commutator need not be positive.

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ gives a counterexample.  You could post an answer to your own question if you want to.

Comment: If anyone wants a reference for this, this counterexample can, e.g., be found on p.8 of Bhatia's book "Positive Definite Matrices" (2007, Princeton University Press). There he also shows that, interestingly, the "converse" holds: if $A>0$ and $AB+BA\geq 0$, then $B$ is necessarily positive semi-definite

Answer (score 3):

Since the "next time" never came for the OP, I post the counterexample given by Jonas Meyer.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$, then $AB+BA=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$   has negative determinant.